# The SSL Certificate we found on this site is not meant for [your_domain_name], probably this is another site on the same server

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

Note: in this post, I changed my actual domain name to [your_domain_name] to make it more generic.

I installed an SSL certificate for apache2 on my linux server. The certificate's type is "positivessl wildcard". I bought it on namecheap. So far, I know it is working just fine on Chrome and Safari for Mac. However, Firefox (for Mac) will issue a warning message of the kind that is not acceptable: `This Connection is Untrusted`. Under "Techical Details", it says:

> [your_domain_name] uses an invalid security certificate. The
>   certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
>   (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

I submitted my domain name to networking4all.

It says:

> Error while checking the SSL Certificate!!
>
> The SSL Certificate we found on this site is not meant for
>   [your_domain_name], probably this is another site on the same server.
>
> We advise you not to submit any confidential or personal data to this
>   website because a secure connection could not be established with this
>   website.

I don't know what that means and I have no idea how to fix it.

Does anyone know what I need to do to solve this? Do I need to issue a new certificate. The thing I am particularly nervous about is: is the certificate busted forever and do I have to buy an entirely new one? Is it a configuration error in apache2?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Candide

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to [install the intermediate certificates](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=881&nav=0,84).

A copy of these should have been included with your certificate, named `ca-bundle` or something similar. If not, download [this](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=120&nav=0,30,1,4) from Comodo. Place it on your server, and set its location in Apache's `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive.

Comment: That was it. The page you mention is leading to another page where you can download the needed certificate. However, I had apparently been mislead previously as I already had installed that certificate: it is only valid until 23 Feb 2012. More certificates including the one that worked eventually can be found [here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=view&parentcategoryid=4). Thanks!

Comment: There are _two_ links in my answer; the second one is probably where you ended up. Anyway, glad to hear it's sorted.

Comment: whoops you're right. Sorry. The point is: the expiration date on these certificates is one to look closely into.